# Not Equivalent Interpretation

Tags: logic

Can someone provide an interpretation to show that the following are not equivalent:

$$\forall x \in D, P(x) \vee Q(x)\;\;\text{vs.}\;\;(\forall x \in D, P(x)) \vee (\forall x \in D, Q(x))$$

They seem equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $D=\Bbb R$ and $P(x)$ mean $x\ge 0$. Can you find a suitable property $Q(x)$?

Comment: $Q(x): x \leq 0?$

Comment: @mathnoob Let's check your suggestion: does $(\forall x\in \Bbb R)(P(x)\lor Q(x))$ hold?

Comment: Ok I see it now.

Comment: @mathnoob Babak's suggestion also works. It's just a minor variant of the one we got. It's basically (but not exactly) letting $P$ mean something and $Q$ be mean $\neg P$.

Comment: Yes the idea is to let $D$ be a domain and partition it into two disjoint halfs. Like let $D = R$. Then $P(x): x$ is rational and $Q(x): x$ is irrational also works.

Comment: @mathnoob You got it.

Comment: @GitGud: It always takes time for you to learn someone a logical fact. And you won Git (+1).

Comment: @BabakS. ^_^ +1 back. And it should be *teach someone*.

Comment: Comment downvoter?

Answer (score 6):

Or; let $D=\mathbb Z$ and $$P(x): x~~~\text{is odd},~~Q(x): x~~~\text{is even}$$

Comment: Great example! You had a great day today (yesterday)!

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks Amy. Yes I had if we can **factor** that terrible assignments. :D

Answer (score 1):

The first statement asserts that for all $x \in D, P$ is true or $Q$ is true. Perhaps both may be true, assuming the statement uses the inclusive OR. However, this statement does not claim that *both* $P \text{ and } Q$ *must* be true for any given $x$. It also does not claim that either (or both) must be true for all $x$.

The second statement on the other hand, claims that either $P$ must be true for all $x$ or $Q$ must be true for all $x$ or both are simultaneously true for all $x$. So for example, with this statement it may not be the case that $P$ is true for all $x$ and $Q$ is true for some $x$ but not others. However, this possibility is included by the first statement.